# Selecting in document not working

Tags: java, url, jsoup

I'm trying to use Jsoup to extract the links in my html-code, but I get an exception saying:

> org.jsoup.nodes.Document cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.Document

And I can't figure out why this goes wrong, since I've followed the tutorials found online.

What my code looks like:

```
    String htmlCode = Jsoup.connect(urlToDownload).get().html();
    Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.parse(htmlCode);
```

Any suggestions on this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
String htmlCode = Jsoup.connect(urlToDownload).get().html();
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = (org.jsoup.nodes.Document) Jsoup.parse(htmlCode);
```